Is there any Kubernetes storage solution that can be run locally and also backed up?
I'm trying to find a kubernetes storage solution that I can use on a local Kubernetes, one node, cluster run with docker desktop on Mac that is also possible to use for backing up persitent volumes in the cluster.
The backup solution that I've tried in combination with storage solution is Velero.
I've tried the following storage solutions:

longhorn: not possible to run on mac OSX since it needs open-iscsi which does not seem to be installable on Mac.
rook-ceph: does not seem to be possible to run on a laptop because of needing three or more disks (?)
openEBS (local PV hostpath): Does not seem to work to take databackups with velero even if the documentation gives the impression that it can. LVM and ZFS does not seem to be usable on a Mac.
https://openebs.io/docs/user-guides/local-storage-user-guide/local-pv-hostpath/hostpath-installation
Data protection using the Velero Backup and Restore.
csi-driver-host-path: Have not managed to get Velero to accept as a provider to use when creating snapshots.


have you tried this? Velero and Minio. https://kdinesh.in/k8sbackup/

From what I understand, are people using minio as a storage for the backups and snapshots. I'm using seaweedFS for this since I do not like the AGPL license of minio (the reason is that I don't understand it).
